Is this subset open with respect to the product topology?
Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, and let $R \subseteq X \times Y$ be a subset of their product space.
I am given the following two conditions:

For any $x \in X$, the set $R_x = \{ y \in Y \mid (x, y) \in R \}$ is an open subset of $Y$.
For any $y \in Y$, the set $R^y = \{ x \in X \mid (x, y) \in R \}$ is an open subset of $X$.

My question is: Is $R$ an open subset $X \times Y$? Thank you for your insights!

What are your thoughts on this?

@DMcMor I feel that $R$ is not necessarily an open set. However, I'm struggling to come up with a counterexample.

$\mathbb{R}^2\setminus {(x, x) : x\in (0, 1)}$ is a counter-example in the plane.

@Jakobian Excellent! Thank you very much

Let $X = Y = \mathbb{R}$ and $R = \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(x, x) : x\in (0, 1)\}$. Then $R_x$ is either whole of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ without a point, which are open. The same holds true for $R^y$. But $R$ is not open in $X\times Y$ since $(0, 0)\in R$ is not a point of its interior.
